# Extract data in subfields of multiple XML files

Tags: python, pandas, xml, group-by, html-parsing

My XML files are stuctured like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<reiXmlPrenos>
  <Qfl>1808</Qfl>
  <fOVE>13.7</fOVE>
  <NetoVolumen>613</NetoVolumen>
  <Hv>104.2</Hv>
  <energenti>
    <energent>
      <sifra>energy_zp</sifra>
      <naziv>Zemeljski plin [kWh]</naziv>
      <vrednost>22482</vrednost>
    </energent>
    <energent>
      <sifra>energy_lb</sifra>
      <naziv>Lesna biomasa [kg]</naziv>
      <vrednost>20482</vrednost>
    </energent>
  <rei>
    <zavetrovanost>2</zavetrovanost>
    <cone>
      <cona>
        <cona_id>1</cona_id>
        <cc_si_cona>1110000</cc_si_cona>
        <visina_cone>2.7</visina_cone>
        <dolzina_cone>14</dolzina_cone>
      </cona>
      <cona>
        <cona_id>2</cona_id>
        <cc_si_cona>120000</cc_si_cona>
      </cona>
  </rei>
</reiXmlPrenos>
```

For several 1,000 XML files I want to read certain values from each and put it in a df. My current code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

podatki = ['Qfl','Hv']

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\...\XMLs')
dir_path = glob.glob('*.xml')
#print(dir_path)

datoteka = (dir_path)

#print(datoteka)

df = pd.concat((pd.read_xml(file, xpath='//reiXmlPrenos')[podatki] for file in datoteka))
df['datoteka'] = datoteka
df = df.set_index('datoteka')
print(df)
```

This works just fine. But the problem are data under sub-categories. E.g. `<energent>` and `<cc_si_cona>`.

I'd like to have a df that would look like this:

```
datoteka  Qfl  Hv    energy_zp  energy_elko  energy_lb  cc_si_cona-1  cc_si_cona-2
xml1     1808  104.2  22482        2482         20482      1110000      120000
```

My try was as following, but it fails.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

podatki = ['Qfl','Hv']

podatki2 = ['sifra']

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\...\XMLs')
dir_path = glob.glob('*.xml')
#print(dir_path)

datoteka = (dir_path)

#print(datoteka)

df = pd.concat((pd.read_xml(file, xpath='//reiXmlPrenos')[podatki] for file in datoteka))
df['datoteka'] = datoteka
df = df.set_index('datoteka')
print(df)

df2 = pd.concat((pd.read_xml(file, xpath='//reiXmlPrenos/energenti/energent')[podatki2] for file in datoteka))
df2['datoteka'] = datoteka
df2 = df2.set_index('datoteka2')
print(df2)
```

So i tried to create a seperate df with a different root and merge the df-s later. But i get a warning:

```
ValueError: Length of values (6) does not match length of index (16)
```

Comment: try `df = pd.read_xml(file, xpath='//reiXmlPrenos')` and inspect df. Values might be there already.

Comment: @LMC No luck. The error states `KeyError: "['cc_si_cona'] not in index"` Any other idea maybe? :(

Answer (score 0):

I made a progress with the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
import pandas as pd

xmldata = r"C:\...\S1.xml"
prstree = ETree.parse(xmldata)
root = prstree.getroot()


# print(root)
store_items = []
all_items = []

for storeno in root.iter('energent'):
    
    cona_sifra = storeno.find('sifra').text
    cona_vrednost = storeno.find('vrednost').text


    store_items = [cona_sifra, cona_naziv, cona_vrednost]
    all_items.append(store_items)

xmlToDf = pd.DataFrame(all_items, columns=[
'sifra', 'naziv', 'vrednost'])

print(xmlToDf.to_string(index=False))
```

This results in:

```
    sifra        vrednost
 energy_e         238981
energy_to          16359
```

Which is fine for 1 example. But i have 1,000 of XML files and the wish is to 1) have all results in 1 row for each XML and 2) to differentiate between different 'sifra' codes.

There can be e.g. `energy_e, energy_en, energy_to`

So ideally the final df would look like this

```
xml     e-sifra  e-vrednost en-sifra  en-vrednost to-naziv  to-vrednost
xml-name1 energy_e    238981      0         0         energy_to  16539
xml-name2...
```

Which can be further simplified in:

```
xml       energy_e   energy_en   energy_to
xml-name    238981      0         16539
```

can it be done?

Comment: @LMZ Is this maybe the way to go?

Comment: @Сергей Кох Is this maybe the way to go?

Comment: @СергейКох Is this maybe the way to go?

Comment: Yes, ElementTree is a good option to ontain data and then populate the dataframe,